# Why can an inferred type cast to an indexed collection whereas a seemingly-identical explicit type cannot?

Tags: typescript

Please can someone explain why my inferred types are accepted as instances of my more general collection type, whereas my explicit types are not?

I was trying to:

- Have part of my app work with tightly defined collections (eg. IParents vs IBosses).
- Have another part of my app work more generally with the same objects (as IPeople).

I wasn't entirely surprised that my types aren't accepted as instances of the general indexed collection type. But I *was* surprised that my inferred types were accepted. I thought the inferred type would act the same as my explicit type.

Do inferred types also get a free indexer? This is not mentioned when the type is described in tooltips.

```
interface IPerson {
    name: string
}

let personA: IPerson = { name: "X" }
let personB: IPerson = { name: "Y" }

// Indexed person collection
interface IPeople {
    [id: string]: IPerson
}

// Explicit person collections
interface IParents {
    mother: IPerson
    father: IPerson
}

interface IBosses {
    manager: IPerson
    director: IPerson
}

// Explicitly-typed instances

let objPeople: IPeople = {
    x: personA,
    y: personB
}

let objParents: IParents = {
    mother: personA,
    father: personB
}

let objBosses: IBosses = {
    manager: personA,
    director: personB
}

// Inferred-typed instances

// Inferred type is { mother: IPerson, father: IPerson } ??
let objInferredParents = {
    mother: personA,
    father: personB,
}

// Inferred type is { manager: IPerson, director: IPerson } ??
let objInferredBosses = {
    manager: personA,
    director: personB,
}

// I want to work elsewhere with the specific types but have this be able to process them all
function processPeople(col: IPeople) {
    // NOP
}

processPeople(objPeople)

// The explicit types are NOT assignable to IPeople
//   "Argument of type 'IParents' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IPeople'.
//      Index signature is missing in type 'IParents'."
processPeople(objParents) // ERROR
processPeople(objBosses) // ERROR

// The inferred types ARE assignable to IPeople
processPeople(objInferredParents)
processPeople(objInferredBosses)
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20IPerson%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20personA%3A%20IPerson%20%3D%20%7B%20name%3A%20%22X%22%20%7D%0D%0Alet%20personB%3A%20IPerson%20%3D%20%7B%20name%3A%20%22Y%22%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Indexed%20person%20collection%0D%0Ainterface%20IPeople%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bid%3A%20string%5D%3A%20IPerson%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Explicit%20person%20collections%0D%0Ainterface%20IParents%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20mother%3A%20IPerson%0D%0A%20%20%20%20father%3A%20IPerson%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20IBosses%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20manager%3A%20IPerson%0D%0A%20%20%20%20director%3A%20IPerson%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Explicitly-typed%20instances%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20objPeople%3A%20IPeople%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20x%3A%20personA%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20y%3A%20personB%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20objParents%3A%20IParents%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20mother%3A%20personA%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20father%3A%20personB%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20objBosses%3A%20IBosses%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20manager%3A%20personA%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20director%3A%20personB%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Inferred-typed%20instances%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Inferred%20type%20is%20%7B%20mother%3A%20IPerson%2C%20father%3A%20IPerson%20%7D%20%3F%3F%0D%0Alet%20objInferredParents%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20mother%3A%20personA%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20father%3A%20personB%2C%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Inferred%20type%20is%20%7B%20manager%3A%20IPerson%2C%20director%3A%20IPerson%20%7D%20%3F%3F%0D%0Alet%20objInferredBosses%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20manager%3A%20personA%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20director%3A%20personB%2C%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20I%20want%20to%20work%20elsewhere%20with%20the%20specific%20types%20but%20have%20this%20be%20able%20to%20process%20them%20all%0D%0Afunction%20processPeople(col%3A%20IPeople)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20NOP%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0AprocessPeople(objPeople)%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20The%20explicit%20types%20are%20NOT%20assignable%20to%20IPeople%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%20%20%22Argument%20of%20type%20'IParents'%20is%20not%20assignable%20to%20parameter%20of%20type%20'IPeople'.%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%20%20%20%20%20Index%20signature%20is%20missing%20in%20type%20'IParents'.%22%0D%0AprocessPeople(objParents)%20%2F%2F%20ERROR%0D%0AprocessPeople(objBosses)%20%2F%2F%20ERROR%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20The%20inferred%20types%20ARE%20assignable%20to%20IPeople%0D%0AprocessPeople(objInferredParents)%0D%0AprocessPeople(objInferredBosses))

Comment: Sorry for inconsistent language. "Cast", "Assignable", "Accepted as".

Comment: Playground link is wrong, no code, just points to the playground

Comment: Sorry, fixed link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IPeople` explicitly allows indexing using any key since it has an index signature. So that means `processPeople` could access any key on an object that does not expect that (for example `processPeople` could access `mother` on `IBosses`)

You could use a generic type parameter that constrains the parameter to have all `IPerson` properties, whatever those properties may be:

```
function processPeople<T extends Record<keyof T, IPerson>>(col: T) {
    // NOP
}

processPeople(objPeople)

processPeople(objParents) // OK
processPeople(objBosses) // Ok

processPeople(objInferredParents)
processPeople(objInferredBosses)
```

Comment: That certainly solves my original problem - many thanks for that. I have never seen keyof. Just tried reading this but I clearly haven't had enough coffee yet: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html

Comment: With the *noImplcitAny* option, I cannot access properties of my parameter. "Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'Record<keyof T, IPerson>' has no index signature." 
Is there a way to avoid the implicit any?

Comment: @Raith You can cast the key you use to access the object to keyof T

Comment: Wow, thanks again. I didn't consider that keyof T works like a type in itself, and could be cast to. I'm learning a lot today.